# Android emulator always with 533MB of internal storage

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

In Eclipse I've created an Android Emulator.

I've set 2000MB as Internal Storage using the configurator, but starting the emulator and looking into Storage properties I Always see 533 MB as total space.

I've tried to add `-partition-size 1024` but the total space is still 533 MB.

My application downloads data from a JSON source and requires at least 600 MB, but I can't understand why emulator doesn't use my configuration.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Even though the devices on the AVD Manager says 1 GB, and the config.ini shows disk.dataPartition.size = 1024M, the emulator's Settings show 533 MB. I tried a Nexus 5, One, Galaxy, etc devices, I tried API 19, 22, 23. I tried different memory limits too. No luck.

Comment: I have exactly same problem. Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I finally was able to solve the issue.

As the sd card size was correctly set up to 1GB, according to my settings, I simply copied the sdcard.img file and renamed it to userdata.img and userdata-qemu.img (in avd folder):

[image]

After relaunching the emulator, the phone memory size has increased! I don't know why, the userdata-qemu.img is much bigger, and I have now 1.89GB total space.

[image]